# Why is jQuery showing this attribute as undefined?

Tags: jquery, attributes, attr

This is what the element looks like from the console:

```
<input type="text" size="20" tabindex="3" id="txtR7163776" name="txtR7163776" selectorviewid="4149027" viewpageid="4877455" class="requiredInput" onfocus="new AutoSuggestControl(this, 4148821, 4149027);" matchfield="name" matchrule="ST" suggtype="rObj" ismultiple="false" autocomplete="off" filtername="R511444" filtervalue="-1">
```

I am trying to remove the attribtes `filtername` and `filtervalue`.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var input = $("#txtR7163776");
   var attrA = input.attr("filtername");
   var attrB = input.attr("filtervalue");
   console.log(attrA, attrB);
   input.removeAttr("filtername");
   input.removeAttr("filtervalue");
});
```

`attrA` and `attrB` are showing as undefined via the console... what am I missing here?

updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var input = $("#txtR7163776");
  console.log(input.length); //1

  var attrA = input.attr("filtername");
  var attrB = input.attr("filtervalue");
  console.log(attrA, attrB); //showing undefined undefined in the console    

  input.removeAttr("filtername");
  input.removeAttr("filtervalue");

    var payroll = $("div[name='Payroll']");

var timekeep = $("div[name='Timekeeping']"); 

var benefits = $("div[name='Benefits']");

var HRIS = $("div[name='HRIS']");

payroll.hide();
timekeep.hide();
benefits.hide();
HRIS.hide();


console.log("A");
$("select[name='oppty_type']").click(function(){
    console.log("B");
    var isPay = false;
    var isTime = false;
    var isBene = false;
    var isHris = false;
    var isPremium = false;
    var isPremiumPlus = false;
    payroll.hide(); 
    timekeep.hide();
        benefits.hide();
    HRIS.hide();


    var multi = [];
    multi = $("select[name='oppty_type']").val(); 
    console.log(multi);
    for(var a = 0; a < multi.length; a++){
        if(multi[a] == 4143371){
            isPay = true;
        }
        if(multi[a] == 4143372){
            isTime = true;
        }
        if(multi[a] == 4143370){
            isHris = true;
        }
        if(multi[a] == 7457612){
            isBene = true;
        }
        if(multi[a] == 58318982){
            isPremium = true;
        }
        if(multi[a] == 58318983){
            isPremiumPlus = true;
        }
    }

    if(isPay){ //payroll

        payroll.show(); 


    }
    if(isTime){ //timekeeping

        timekeep.show();


    }
    if(isHris){ //HRIS

        HRIS.show();


    }
    if(isBene){ //Benefits

        benefits.show();



    }
    if(isPremium){ //bundle premium

        payroll.show(); 


        timekeep.show();


        benefits.show();



    }
    if(isPremiumPlus){ //bundle premium plus 

        payroll.show(); 


        timekeep.show();


        benefits.show();


        HRIS.show();

    }

    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you make a snippet?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsbin.com/hadukojifi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: `attrA.removeAttr("filtername");` doesn't make any sense. simplified, it's the same as `"R511444".removeAttr("filtername");`

Comment: I'm sorry what is a snippet?

Comment: @RyanPaceSloan Press Ctrl + M. Something like jsFiddle or jsBin, which can execute and show.

Comment: They're showing `undefined`? That doesn't make sense. What does `console.log($("*#txtR7163776").length)` show?

Comment: made the adjustment ... to the question to reflect the changes ...

Comment: @RyanPaceSloan See my answer, there's a link. What you said that didn't work, works perfectly. Can you kindly check?

Comment: @stryner ... it shows 1

Comment: This is a customization of an existing software platform that autogenerates the pages (Rollbase). The issue is the that a lookup field is filtering the values so they are not displaying. I am trying to remove the filter using jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following won't work:

```
attrA.removeAttr("filtername");
attrB.removeAttr("filtervalue");
```

Because you are operating them on a `attrA` and `attrB`, which are `string`. The above statement roughly translates to a meaning less:

```
"R511444".removeAttr("filtername");
"-1".removeAttr("filtername");
```

You have to be doing:

```
input.removeAttr("filtername");
input.removeAttr("filtervalue");
```

But in the console I am getting both the `attr` values:

[image]

**Output: http://jsbin.com/hadukojifi/edit?html,js,console,output**

Comment: Excellent. Lemme try it out...I'm customizing an existing platform called Rollbase to remove theses attributes from a field that are keeping data from displaying correctly, I wonder if there is something else I'm not seeing?

Comment: removing the attributes probably isn't having the effect you were hoping for. It's likely whatever the attributes are doing has already happened by the time you are removing them, making this an X/Y problem.

Comment: You need to show us the full code to tell what you are missing. `:)` So that we can help you better. What say @KevinB?

Comment: Yes Praveen, yours works...mine doesn't because of something we can't see yet due to Rollbase I suspect.

Comment: Shall we talk in Chat?

Comment: forget about the Y problem and instead solve X. in this case the Y problem is how to remove the attribute. Instead, try solving whatever you wanted removing the attribute to solve.

Comment: @RyanPaceSloan When you are trying to do something, tell that problem. Don't feel that "Well, this would solve" and ask how to do the "this". That's XY Problem.

Comment: Come on... StackOverflow, trigger that chat! LoL.

Comment: Keep talking and it will ask us to move the discussion into chat. :P

Comment: @praveen  I could send you a web meeting so we could share screens

Comment: Let's first understand the problem.

Comment: Click on the link and come to the chat.

Comment: @RyanPaceSloan I am waiting in the chat room. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are removing attribute from `attrA` and `attrB` instead of `input`. Try like following

```
input.removeAttr("filtername");
input.removeAttr("filtervalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the index 0 at your input var declaration

```
var input = $("#txtR7163776")[0]
```

maybe your jquery version is returning an array and you miss that.. in my jquery version your code works fine,,

Comment: This is an XY problem and totally different one. Solved by speaking with them directly. :)